# Using shared_ptr as class member

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, pointers

I have already got the answer for my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40946536), and I decided to use `std::vector<int>` instead of `int *`. I have written the following code. Am I use `shared_ptr` properly now?

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(unsigned size, std::string name) {
        _size = size;
        _name = name;
        _arr = std::make_shared<std::vector<int> >(size, 0);
    }

    MyClass(const MyClass& other) {
        _arr = other._arr;
        _size = other._size;
    }

    MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& other) {
        _arr = other._arr;
        _size = other._size;
    }

    void setArrAt(unsigned index, int value) {
        if (index < _size)
            (*_arr.get())[index] = value;
    }

    void setArr(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int> > &arr) {
        _arr = arr;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int> >& getArr() {
        return _arr;
    }

    void print() {
        std::cout << _name << " : ";
        for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
            std::cout << (*_arr.get())[i] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    ~MyClass() { }

private:
    std::shared_ptr< std::vector<int> > _arr;
    unsigned _size;
    std::string _name;
};

int main() {
    MyClass alice(2, "Alice");
    alice.setArrAt(0, 10);
    alice.setArrAt(1, 20);
    MyClass bob(2, "Bob");
    // some code
    bob.setArr(alice.getArr());
    alice.print(); // "Alice : 10 20"
    bob.print(); // "Bob : 10 20"

    bob.setArrAt(0, 100);
    alice.print(); // "Alice : 100 20"
    bob.print(); // "Bob : 100 20"
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. I use `_` in names of variables only for clarity.

Comment: I really didn't see any benefit of using shared_ptr in here rather than unique_ptr? Also for clarity I would suggest to put m as a prefix for the member variables rather than putting an underscore.

Comment: @OnurA. I actually don't use underscores in my code, it's only for this example.

Comment: I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. The example code that you have posted is not reviewable in this form because it leaves us guessing at your intentions.  Unlike Stack Overflow, Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/41243)

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` already takes care of managing the memory of a dynamically growing array. Storing a pointer to the vector only complicates stuff and reduces performance due to an extra indirection when accessing the elements of a vector.

Other than that, I would only expose shared pointers via getters/setters when wanting to actually share the lifetime of resources. Returning a (const) reference to the object is much cleaner if the calling code only wants to access it, not control it's lifetime.

Why do you also store `_size`? The vector already stores it's current size.

What happens to `_name` if you copy the object? It's been left out of the copy constructor & assignment operators. These two also duplicate code which can be avoided with the copy-and-swap idiom.

Comment: If `alice` and `bob` have identical `_array`, this vector<int> will be deleted twice: in alice.~MyClass() and bob.~MyClass(), and I will get segfault. Am I right?

Comment: No, by storing the `std::vector` as a member of the class (not as a (smart) pointer), each instance of the class has a different vector.

Comment: Yes, but I need identical vectors. Also, `MyClass` is not my implementation of vector.

Comment: @AnatoliySultanov, describe the situation in the post itself then. Currently people think that it is hypothetical code. Also, try to rename `MyClass` into something considerable, that will give more context to your post and make it actually reviewable.